# Clickable link not under image

Tags: html, css

I've been doing web design for a few years now. I'm doing a mock up of a banner image in the header of a wordpress theme. Normally image links are no problem, but in this case the whole image is not clickable. Only the right side of the image is a link. Why is this? How do I fix it?

[Website link](http://scottishsnooker.com/)

The banner advert is the one in the top right 'PremiumCues'.

Could any of you guys help me?

Comment: On my screen "The National Governing Body for Snooker in Scotland" sits on top of that banner, obscuring it.

Comment: should your banner really be fixed?

Comment: Why are you positioning it with "margin-left" and "margin-top" instead using "left" and "top"?

Comment: @j08691 Thanks, sorted it now, should work on all screen resolutions.

Comment: @EricLemos Fail to see what your referring to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have your `rt-container` overlapping the image. A simple solution would just be to make sure your div with the banner in it is truly rendered on top of the rt-container div. To do this, just set a higher z-index. Just add this to your css

```
#banner {
z-index:100;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the helpful response.

Answer (score 1):

remove this:

```
.rt-container, .rt-block {
   position: relative;
}
```

or add

```
#banner {
    z-index: 9999; /* any large number */
}
```